# Dozer. Checking equality

Tags: java, equals, dozer

Is there any way to check if two objects are equal using dozer?
For example, we've got class Foo:

```
class Foo {
   String name;
   String color;
   int id;
   public boolean equals(Object o) {
      if (o instanse of Foo) {
         return id.equals(((Foo)o).getId();}
      else return false;
   }
```

and two instanses:

```
Foo a = new Foo();
a.setId(1);
a.setName("first");

Foo b = new Foo();
b.setId(1);
b.setName("second");
```

How can you see, a.equals(b) will return true, but can we somehow check by all fields?

Comment: If those two objects aren't equal, then why does your equals method say they're equal?

Comment: @immibis for example, first object - entity in db, second is user-editted entity, that I need to save or update